# SUMIF with several conditions with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a google apps script similar to SUMIF in google sheets. My goal is to sum all values in column hours for all rows which contain a particular ID (id) during a defined period (column period), which are marked as productive (productive  = 1) and the value of column unit for the particular row is different from the string stated bellow. For some reason, it does not work. I am new to javascript and can't figure out the reason why it is not working. I tried defining a sum function and then call it for each of the values in the id column (about 7000 rows).

```
//Productive hours  
//=if($A2<> "", SUMIFS(hours,hrmid,$AC2, productive,1,period,$A2)-SUMIFS(hours,hrmid,$AC2, productive,1,period,$A2, units,"Revision Stand-by"), "")
  function sumPrdHrs (item) {
    var hoursToSum = 0;
    var summedHrs = [];
    var hours = ytdSheet.getRange(2,18, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var productive = ytdSheet.getRange(2,33, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var units = ytdSheet.getRange(2, 9, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var id= ytdSheet.getRange(2,29, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var period = ytdSheet.getRange(2,1, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    //var date = ytdSheet.getRange(2,1, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    
    for (var i=0; i < hours.length; i++) {
      if ((id[i][0] == item) && (productive[i][0] == 1) && (period[i][0] == period[i+1][0]) && (units[i][0] != "Revision Stand-by")) {
      hoursToSum += hours[i][0];
      summedHrs.push(hoursToSum);
      }      
    }
    return sumPrdHrs;
    console.log(summedHrs);
}
  
function productiveHrs () {

  var id= ytdSheet.getRange(2,29, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var sumHours = [];
  
  id.forEach(function(item,i) {
                
     var summedHours = sumPrdHrs (item);    
    
    //sumHours.push(summedHours);
    
    //Logger.log(summedHours);
    
   // ytdSheet.getRange(2,31,hrmId.length,1).setValues(summedHours);
                
                });
```

}

Comment: can you give a screenshot on what you are trying to work on?

Comment: Updated my answer below. Also provided some changes with your conditions that I think would be better suited with what you are doing. So far, it does what your functions want to achieve. If you have additional conditions you want to be added, you should be able to add them easily. feel free to comment below if you need some assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some questionable lines on your code, I'll discuss them below in comparison with the code I have created and tested based on what you want to achieve and still makes sense.

```
function sumPrdHrs (item) {
    var hoursToSum = 0; 

    // Removed summedHrs array. Based on your code structure, you want to return the sum of productive hours. 
    // I don't see any use of creating an array when you can already sum it up directly.

    var hours = ytdSheet.getRange(2,18, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var productive = ytdSheet.getRange(2,33, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var units = ytdSheet.getRange(2, 9, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var id= ytdSheet.getRange(2,29, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var period = ytdSheet.getRange(2,1, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    
    for (var i=0; i < hours.length; i++) {
      // In the conditions below, I don't get why you want to compare current period to the period below. 
      // It always makes the last item with the same period invalid since there is no last date. 
      // But will include it since it might be important to you
      // You also have another condition mentioned but wasn't added initially so I skipped it for now. But feel free to add it on your code.
      if ((id[i][0] == item) && (productive[i][0] == 1) && (period[i][0] == period[i+1][0]) && (units[i][0] != "Revision Stand-by")) {
        hoursToSum += hours[i][0]; 
        // Total hours is calculated per item, that's all you need to return below.
      }      
    }
    return hoursToSum;
}

// Based on what you want, this will sum all hours per item that follows the conditions above.
function productiveHrs () {
  // This will transform the 2d array into 1d array 
  var id = ytdSheet.getRange(2,29, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  // We want to loop only the unique items, removing duplicates
  id = id.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i);
  
  var sumHours = [];

  id.forEach(function(item,i) {
    // Skip blank/invalid items
    if(item) {
      var summedHours = sumPrdHrs(item);    
      sumHours.push(summedHours);      
    }
  });

  Logger.log(sumHours);
}
```

This is my sample sheet

[image: sample sheet]

This is the output

[image: sample output]

See that the total of item `b` which should be 14 is 10 right? That's because of the period condition that checks the period below. That's what I discussed above.

What you can do instead with the "period vs period below" condition is get the unique dates per item, and then sum them per date, per item.

This should be a better way checking period.

```
// Added time for per item summation of hours
function sumPrdHrs (item, time) {
    var hoursToSum = 0;
    var hours = ytdSheet.getRange(2,18, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var productive = ytdSheet.getRange(2,33, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var units = ytdSheet.getRange(2, 9, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var id = ytdSheet.getRange(2,29, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var period = ytdSheet.getRange(2,1, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    
    for (var i=0; i < hours.length; i++) {
      // Compare period[i][0] to unique period fetched from productiveHrs() instead.
      if ((id[i][0] == item) && (productive[i][0] == 1) && (period[i][0] == time) && (units[i][0] != "Revision Stand-by")) {
        hoursToSum += hours[i][0];
      }      
    }
    return hoursToSum;
}

function productiveHrs () {
  // Get unique ids and periods
  var id = ytdSheet.getRange(2,29, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var period = ytdSheet.getRange(2,1, ytdSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  id = id.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i);
  period = period.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i);
  
  var sumHours = [];

  // Traverse all combination of id and period
  id.forEach(function(item,i) {
    if(item) {
      period.forEach(function(time,j) {
        if(time) {
          // Pass period to sum hours under item per period
          var summedHours = sumPrdHrs(item, time);    
          // Only push data when where is summedHours
          if (summedHours) { 
            sumHours.push([item, time, summedHours]);  
          }    
        }  
      });
    }
  });

  Logger.log(sumHours);
}
```

This is the sample data:

[image: sample data revision]

This is the output:

[image: sample output revision]

As you can see, a prettier and more readable output and conditions that would make sense.

If you have some clarifications and additional questions, feel free to comment below.

Comment: Thanks @Marios, I am still awaiting OPs comment/verification as he did mention some conditions that I did not include in my code. Although, what I think he tries to achieve is already included here. and if he does want some conditions added, he can easily add them on.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nazi A! Your solution perfectly solved my problem! I see what was wrong with my code.